# splunk_for_vmware_appliance folder missing

Tags: splunk

I need to set my ESXi host to work with Splunk, I have only that one unmanaged host, here: 
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/VMW/latest/Install/Asimpleengine.conf 
I saw that I need to create my engine.conf file in `$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps/splunk_for_vmware_appliance/local`, but thare's no splunk_for_vmware_appliance folder where bin and .metadata folders should be stored too. How it's possible that folder isn't there? What should I do to compile my engine.conf and inputs.conf files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splunk stopped supporting ESXi hosts, which works without vCenter, that's why compiler isn't there. It wasn't used so they decided to suport only with vCenter. Their tutorial wasn't updated yet.